# Creating random SVG curves in JavaScript while avoiding sharp turns

Tags: javascript, algorithm, svg, random, curve

The snippet below draws random connected curves over the document a certain number of times:

```js
function createPath() {
  const 
    dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), svg = document.querySelector( `svg` ),
    path = document.createElementNS( `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, `path` );
  
  dimensions[0] = dimensions[0]; dimensions[1] = dimensions[1];
  svg.appendChild( path );
  
  path.setAttribute(
    `d`,
    `M ` +
    `${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber(dimensions[1])} `+
    `C `+ 
    `${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber( dimensions[1])}, `+  
    
    `${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber( dimensions[1])}, `+
    
    `${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber( dimensions[1])} `
  )
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 100; i++  ) {
    path.setAttribute(
      `d`,
      path.getAttribute( `d` ) + 
      `S `+`${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber(dimensions[1])},`+
      
      `${getRandomNumber(dimensions[0])} `+`${getRandomNumber(dimensions[1])} `
    )
  }
}

setInterval( setSVGDimensions, 10 ); setInterval( positionPath, 10 );
createPath();
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
svg {
  border-radius: 1rem; background-color: rgba( 95%,95%,95%,0.5 );
  filter: blur( 1rem );

  animation-name: blur; animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 0.25rem; fill: none;
}

@keyframes blur {
  100% { filter: blur( 0rem ); }
}

path {
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 2500s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier( 0.75,0.25,0.25,1 );

  stroke-dasharray: 1000000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000000;  
  stroke: rgba( 0%,100%,75%,0.75 );
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script>
  function getRandomNumber( max ) { return Math.floor( Math.random() * max ); }

  function getWindowDimensions() {
    const 
      dimensions = [],
      windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    dimensions.push( windowWidth, windowHeight );
    return dimensions;
  }
  
  function setSVGDimensions() {
    const 
      dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), svg = document.querySelector( `svg` );

    svg.style.width = dimensions[0] - 10; svg.style.height = dimensions[1] - 10;
  }  
  
  function positionPath() {
    const
      dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), path = document.querySelector( `path` );

      path.setAttribute( 
        `transform`, 
        `
          scale( 0.5 ) translate( ${ dimensions[0] / 2 },${ dimensions[1] / 3 } )
        ` 
      )
  }  
</script>
```

This is the desired behavior except for the sharpness of some curves. The radius is too small, the angle is too acute. We want wider smoother curves. For example in this screenshot the problem areas are circled.

In the picture below notice the red circles have very sharp curves whereas the green circled are wider smoother curves:

[image]

**Is there a way we could use JavaScript to prevent the creation of the sharp curves** ( circled in red ) **and have the algorithm only create wider curves** ( circled in green )?

Comment: @enxaneta if you inspect the HTML output of my code you will see that only `S` commands are used after the first `C` command. This accomplishes making every subsequent line a curve instead of a straight line - but given that the end points are random some of these curves are very sharp. What I'm looking for is a way to calculate if the subsequent curve will be too narrow or not - and only draw a curve that will generate a wide one. `S` just tells the next 2 values to generate another curve - it has nothing to do with the wideness or narrowness of a curve.

Comment: One way to get smooth wide curves is to make sure that both bezier curve control points lie within a square whose bisection line is the line connecting start and destination points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added some functions to check if the angle between last two points and the next one is not less than the `MIN_ANGLE`. Now it is 60 degrees, but it can be wider to get bigger radius of curves.

I've also added `MIN_DISTANCE` because too short distance between two points provides sharp curves too.

```js
let lastTwoPoints = [];
const MIN_ANGLE = 60;
const MIN_DISTANCE = (Math.min(...getWindowDimensions()))/10;

function getPoint(){
    let point = [getRandomNumber(getWindowDimensions()[0]),getRandomNumber(getWindowDimensions()[1])];

    if(lastTwoPoints.length < 2){
        lastTwoPoints.push(point);
    } else {
            if(getAngle(...lastTwoPoints, point) < MIN_ANGLE || getDistance(lastTwoPoints[1],point) < MIN_DISTANCE){
            point = getPoint();
        } else {
            lastTwoPoints.shift();
            lastTwoPoints.push(point);
        }
    }      
    return point;
}

function pointString(){
    let point = getPoint();
    return `${point[0]} ${point[1]} `;
}

function getDistance(pointA, pointB){
    return Math.sqrt((pointA[0] - pointB[0])**2 + (pointA[1] - pointB[1])**2);
}

function getAngle(pointA, pointB, pointC){ // angle to pointB
    let a = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
    let b = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
    let c = getDistance(pointC, pointA);
    return Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2*a*b))*(180/Math.PI);
}

function createPath() {
    const 
    dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), svg = document.querySelector( `svg` ),
    path = document.createElementNS( `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, `path` );

    dimensions[0] = dimensions[0]; dimensions[1] = dimensions[1];
    svg.appendChild( path );

    path.setAttribute(
    `d`,
    `M ` +
    `${pointString()}`+
    `C `+ 
    `${pointString()}`+  

    `${pointString()}`+

    `${pointString()}`
    )


    for( let i = 0; i < 100; i++  ) {
    path.setAttribute(
    `d`,
    path.getAttribute( `d` ) + 
    `S `+`${pointString()}`+

    `${pointString()}`
    )
    }
}

setInterval( setSVGDimensions, 10 ); setInterval( positionPath, 10 );
createPath();

function getRandomNumber( max ) { return Math.floor( Math.random() * max ); }

function getWindowDimensions() {
    const 
    dimensions = [],
    windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    dimensions.push( windowWidth, windowHeight );
    return dimensions;
}

function setSVGDimensions() {
    const 
    dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), svg = document.querySelector( `svg` );

    svg.style.width = dimensions[0] - 10; svg.style.height = dimensions[1] - 10;
}  

function positionPath() {
    const
    dimensions = getWindowDimensions(), path = document.querySelector( `path` );

    path.setAttribute( 
    `transform`, 
    `
    scale( 0.5 ) translate( ${ dimensions[0] / 2 },${ dimensions[1] / 3 } )
    ` 
    )
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
svg {
  border-radius: 1rem; background-color: rgba( 95%,95%,95%,0.5 );
  filter: blur( 1rem );

  animation-name: blur; animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 0.25rem; fill: none;
}

@keyframes blur {
  100% { filter: blur( 0rem ); }
}

path {
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 2500s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier( 0.75,0.25,0.25,1 );

  stroke-dasharray: 1000000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000000;  
  stroke: rgba( 0%,100%,75%,0.75 );
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

**I've cleaned up the code, added `MAX_DISTANCE` to check:**

```js
let lastTwoPoints = [];

const W = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const H = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

const MIN_ANGLE = 60;
const MIN_DISTANCE = (Math.min(W,H))/20;
const MAX_DISTANCE = (Math.min(W,H))/4;

let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let path = document.querySelector('path');

svg.style.width = W;
svg.style.height = H;

createPath();

function getPoint(){
        let x = getRandomNumber(W*0.6) + W*0.2;
    let y = getRandomNumber(H*0.6) + H*0.2;
        
    let point = [x,y];

    if(lastTwoPoints.length < 2){
        lastTwoPoints.push(point);
    } else {
        if(getAngle(...lastTwoPoints, point) < MIN_ANGLE
            || getDistance(lastTwoPoints[1],point) < MIN_DISTANCE
            || getDistance(lastTwoPoints[1],point) > MAX_DISTANCE){
            point = getPoint();
        } else {
            lastTwoPoints.shift();
            lastTwoPoints.push(point);
        }
    }
    return point;
}

function pointString(){
    let point = getPoint();
    return `${point[0]} ${point[1]} `;
}

function getDistance(pointA, pointB){
    return Math.sqrt((pointA[0] - pointB[0])**2 + (pointA[1] - pointB[1])**2);
}

function getAngle(pointA, pointB, pointC){ // angle to pointB
    let a = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
    let b = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
    let c = getDistance(pointC, pointA);
    return Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2*a*b))*(180/Math.PI);
}

function createPath() {

       let path_string = `M ${pointString()} C ${pointString()} ${pointString()} ${pointString()}`;

    for( let i = 0; i < 100; i++  ) {
      path_string += `S ${pointString()} ${pointString()} `
    }
    
    path.setAttribute('d', path_string);
}


function getRandomNumber(max) { return Math.floor( Math.random() * max ); }
```

```html
<svg fill="none" stroke="black">
    <path d=""/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a major improvement. It does fail sometimes and produce very sharp angles but for the most part it's something I can build off of. Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem comes when last point is near to outline. So the `getAngle` function can't find the right solution in those cases. Especially when it gets to corner, only 44 degrees of MIN_ANGLE will certainly resolve the situation. Also that is the result of this situation when we have sharp-like angles. That's because of it was the only way to get out of the situation when last point comes near to corner or even border of canvas. So you are going to rethink this issue))) Some "plan B" variants of behavior in those cases... As an example it might be a circular field of points only.

Comment: `canvas.getContext('2d').isPointInPath(path, point[0], point[1])` - where `path` - is oval-like field for points. Oval should be inscribed in bounding rectangle. So that will be the first test of new point - if it is in the oval-shaped figure. Ideally it should be not oval, but a circle-shaped canvas. I don't know if we have similar examination method in SVG.